# nextjs rewrites gives 404

Tags: reactjs, next.js, reverse-proxy

In my local environment I'm trying to reach the development server which is in https://api.mydomain.com

When I made the call from my nextjs/reactjs app I get CORS error, so I try to fix it with reverse proxy on next in the following way:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [{
      source: "/api/:path*",
      destination: "https://api.mydomain.com/:path*",
    }]
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And in the app I'm calling the backend in the following way:

```
const login = async (user: any) => {
    const data = await fetch("/api/v1/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    });
    return data;
  };
```

As the result I get a 404 error, but without any body. So it seems that it's not reaaching the server.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

But If I call directly the server to the following url, it works fine https://api.mydomain.com/v1/auth/login it works

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, You can solve this by 2 methods:-

1st Check the CORS Options that you are set in your backend. If you are not allowed the option that you are using please allow it. For example, in NodeJs

[image]

2nd Its Also occurs when your backend & frontend are hosted on the same server and you are calling your backend from serverside with the domain name. In that case, you have to use localhost instead of the domain and the problem will solve. For example, I made two variables in my .env file

DOMAIN_API_URL=https://api.mydomain.com

SERVER_SIDE_API_URL=http://localhost:4000

Note:- If you are still getting the 404 issues then it is not the issue of CORS. You have to check, your frontend is not able to find any apis or not able to trigger the correct URL.